# Can 2 or more inputs be processed at the same time in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using a tool-A, which is written in python, to analyse an input. Another external tool ET1 produces an output, which is than used as an input for tool-A. The whole process occurs in real time.
Suppose that I have two external tools (ET1 and ET2) that sent inputs to tool-A at the same time, is there a way that tool-A could process both inputs at the same time? 
Unfortunately, I am not familiar with paralel processing in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create another instance of tool-A then you can assign ET1 and ET2 to seperate threads so ET1 and ET2 will put their output to their own instance of tool-A. If tool-A must be a singleton object then you can only run ET1 and ET2 in parallel but you have to wait for tool-A to consume their outputs in the order which tool finishes first. You should probably checkout concept of `mutex`.